# Oracle Constraint with three columns, but only one row can equal a certain value

Tags: oracle, constraints, unique, multiple-columns

This might sound easy and it might be.   I have 3 columns, one with a constant string (name), one column (status) with two options (foreign keys) and another (room_id) that is a parent key from another table, how can I ensure that only one row is set to an "ON" value for the same name.  There cannot be multiple rows with an "ON" value having the same name, but can be multiple rows with an "OFF" value for the same NAME.   Example.

```
room_id       name       status
1             daniel       ON   --- OK for only one ON to be set for daniel
2             daniel       OFF
3             daniel       OFF
4             daniel       OFF
5             daniel       OFF
6             daniel       ON  --- THIS IS NOT ALLOWED...  but everything is UNIQUE
1             jeff         OFF
2             jeff         OFF
3             jeff         ON  --- OK for only ONE to be set to "ON" for jeff.
4             jeff         ON  --- THIS IS NOT ALLOWED... the room_id keeps things UNIQUE
5             jeff         ON  --- THIS IS NOT ALLOWED...
```

The below UNIQUE constraint allows multiple "ON" values with the same name.

```
ADD CONSTRAINT constratin_name_uq UNIQUE (room_id, name, status)
```

I believe I need a CHECK constraint also, but with a COUNT not greater than 1 on the status column where value = 'ON'...  to ensure there is only one "NAME" and "STATUS" with an ON value....

The constraint below will not allow multiple "OFF" values, which is needed in my case.

```
ADD CONSTRAINT constraint_name_uq UNIQUE (name, status)
```

Also...  Everything can be "OFF", but only one "ON" for each given name.

Any help is appreciated,

Thank you,
Daniel

Comment: you may need to use a before trigger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create the unique index:

```sql
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX table_name__status_name__u
  ON table_name( CASE status WHEN 'ON' THEN name END );
```

Which, for the table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (
  room_id NUMBER
          NOT NULL,
  name    VARCHAR2(10)
          NOT NULL,
  status  VARCHAR2(3)
          NOT NULL
          CHECK ( STATUS IN ( 'ON', 'OFF' ) )
);
```

Then this works:

```sql
INSERT INTO table_name ( room_id, name, status )
SELECT 1, 'alice', 'ON' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'alice', 'OFF' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'alice', 'OFF' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 'alice', 'OFF' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 'alice', 'OFF' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 6, 'alice', 'OFF' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'beatrice', 'OFF' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'beatrice', 'OFF' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'beatrice', 'OFF' FROM DUAL;
```

However, this:

```sql
INSERT INTO table_name ( room_id, name, status )
SELECT 7, 'alice', 'ON' FROM DUAL;
```

Fails with:

> ```
> ORA-00001: unique constraint (FIDDLE_XFKAWDIVOXGJZVQESSZQ.TABLE_NAME__STATUS_NAME__U) violated
> ```

and this also fails with the same exception:

```sql
INSERT INTO table_name ( room_id, name, status )
SELECT 4, 'beatrice', 'ON' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 'beatrice', 'ON' FROM DUAL;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=d36db5d8537a846814a35b1c006eb77d)*

Comment: The table where room_id is coming from already has check constraint so that the values are only "ON" or "OFF".   So the UNIQUE index alone will do the trick?

Comment: Sorry for all the updates/deleted comments...  after further testing, it is working.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You have redundant data in your database. Once a room is turned ON for a given name, all other rooms are known (according to your business rule) to be OFF for that name and should not be stored as such in the database. Just have a "person_location" table, with two columns, name and current (ON) room_id number. For those times when the person isn't anywhere, his room_id should be set to NULL. Assuming the person can't be in more than one place at one time (again, this seems to be your business rule), you could make things even more simple by making their current location an additional column in the already existing master person table, saving you from having to create this extra table in the first place.